# how to sync and write all to text?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, semaphore

multithreaded fence lines from a text file, then sending a request form post \ get to that data after receiving a positive response in writing to another text file.

```
public int index = -1;
public int count = 1000;

private static readonly object SyncIndex = new object();
private static readonly object SyncFiles = new object();

public void CreateThreads(int threads)
{
    Thread[] threadArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < (threadArray = new Thread[threads]).Length; i++)
    {
        threadArray[i] = new Thread(this.Run) { IsBackground = true };
        threadArray[i].Start();
    }
}


public void Run()
{
    while (true)
    {
      lock(SyncIndex) { index++;}
      //if (index > count) { break; }
      string resp = Check(index.ToString());

      lock (SyncFiles)
      {
          if (resp == "true")
          {
              SaveText("good.txt", index.ToString());
          }
          else
          {
              SaveText("bad.txt", index.ToString());
          }
      }

    }
 }

public string Check(string login)
{
    try
    {
        System.Net.WebRequest reqGET = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=" + login);
        System.Net.WebResponse resp = reqGET.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(stream);
        string s = sr.ReadToEnd();

        if (s.Contains("true"))
        {
            return "true";
        }
        else
        {
            return "false";
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Check(login);
    }
    return "";
}

//static ReaderWriterLockSlim cacheLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
private static void SaveText(string file, string text)
{
    //cacheLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        var write = new StreamWriter(file, true);
        write.WriteLine(text);
        write.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    //finally
    //{
    //    cacheLock.ExitWriteLock();
    //}
}

private void btStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateThreads(300);
}
```

what is problem?
count = 1000
threads = 300

```
bad.txt
299
300
301
302
303
304
305
306
307
308
310
311
312
313
314
315
316

good.txt
309
```

Why text then start at 300?
where did I go wrong??????

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd recommend not launching one thread per work item.  Use `Parallel.For` instead of making the threads yourself.

Not only will this prevent the bug (you can use the index directly), but it will also load balance more effectively.

That being said, your problem is that you're using the same variable in every thread.  You need to make a temporary:

```
int localIndex;
lock(SyncIndex) 
{ 
    index++;
    localIndex = index; // Copy this here, before another thread can change it
}

// Use localIndex, not index, from here on...
```

In your current code, you synchronize the increment of index, but other threads will still "change" its value before you can use it.

Comment: and you would not be able to do this more details on my code? sorry for bad english

Comment: @user2429282 Just swap my code in for yours, and change every instance of "index" with "localIndex" in the Run method... That will maek your code work.  That being said, StackOverflow is not intended to "write your code for you" - we're here to help answer specific questions, not do your work ;)